# is_writable($dir) not working

Tags: php-5.3, phpdesigner

when I was working with thix thix ix all fine it ix showing all the subfolder and than subfolders of the subfolders

```php
<?php

function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $Folders = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($folders as $subFolders){
        if($subFolders != '.' && $subFolders != '..'){
             echo '<li>'.$subFolders;
             if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$subFolder)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$subFolders);
             echo '</li>';
         }
    }

    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('/home/');

?>
```

but when i changed the code a little bit to check whether any folder is writable than it gave me nothing neither an error nor shown the results..
at the line

```php
if($subFolders != '.' && $subFolders != '..'){
                if(is_writable($subFolders)){
        echo '<li>'.$subFolders.' is witeable :) ';
```

Comment: "i was working with thix thix ix all fine it ix showing", what do you mean ?

Comment: please post full updated code

Comment: bro this is the full code..

Comment: actually for my server im making a small php script which can check whether the directory is writable or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but missing the full file name. Need the `$dir.'/'.` part (the parent path):

`if(is_writable($dir.'/'.$subFolders)){`

Comment: are you sure the file is writable to the user owning the web server software? because the code above should in fact be testing whether the file/folder is writable...

Comment: okay i tried ($dir.'/'.$folder.'/'.$subFolders) but not working

Comment: the `.$folder.'/'` part should not be there; there's no reference to a `$folder` variable anywhere in your code.